# How do I Identify navigation away from form in D365 Model driven app from opening child entity form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, autosave, powerapps-modeldriven

We have disabled autosave on one opportunity form as mentioned in -[MS learn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/manage-auto-save?view=op-9-1)

So, we prevented savemode = 2 (moving away from the form) and savemode = 70 (30 second autosave after edit).

Customer wants user to be prompted if the form is changed and they try to move away from the form (clicking on the left navigation, or clicking back arrow), but they also want autosave to happen if they open a child entity form from any of the subgrids on the form. As the savemode = 2 in both the cases, we are unable to differentiate and hence not able to satisfy the requirement.

Any one has figured out how we can differentiate between these two events?